# Plotly - 3D Surface Plot

Tags: plotly

all I am using the [following](https://plot.ly/javascript/3d-surface-plots/) 3D surface graph. I would like to pass the x, y and z coordinates separately. However online I read that the z data needs to be a 2D array but it does not seem to be explained in the documentation what the 2D array should consist of. Perhaps someone already has some experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: Think of each array inside the array for `z` as a contour data series to be associated with the corresponding data points from the `x` and `y` arrays (by array index position). And as the figure reference points out, if you don't supply the `x` and `y` arrays, "the x and y coordinates are assumed to be linear starting at 0 with a unit step".

Comment: Re the x and y being linear starting at 0 that's right - because I read it in the documentation.

So if I want to think of the x, y and z coordinates as separate - should I pass the same array twice? As to have the same z data corresponding to the x and y arrays (also passed).